# How to identify which image tag is calling the mouseHover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've four links on my HTML page. The code is as follows :

```
<a class="lb" href="home.php"><img id="imgH" src="Bhome.png" onmouseover="onHover();"/></a>
<a class="lb" href="AboutUs.php"><img id ="imgA" src="Babout.png" onmouseover="onHover();" /></a>
<a class="lb" href="code.php"><img id ="imgC" src="Bcode.png" onmouseover="onHover();" /></a>
<a class="lb" href="login.php"><img id="imgL" src="Blogin.png" onmouseover="onHover();" /></a>
```

On hover, I'd like to change the corresponding image to a different one. I do not wish to write a different function for every image tag. In the Javascript function, how do I find out which img tag called the onHover function?

Comment: What did you try? show us your code.

Comment: You can use `onHover.call(this)` and `this` inside it will be that image element

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon - I've not tried much yet. I've no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Well anyway, both posted answer are good and PSL said what i would do.

Comment: you could get the id of each img tag by passing this as parameter to the onHover() function and var id=this.id in js

Comment: @PSL - How do I compare what is contined in this? Based on the calling tag, I'll have to use a document.getElementById('').attr() function.

Comment: @user657592 inside the hover just do `this.src= "someothersrc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the element :

```
..... onmouseover="onHover(this)";
```

and just do

```
function onHover(elem) {
    elem.src = 'someother_image.png';
}
```

or use a jQuery event handler :

```
$('#imgH, #imgA, #imgC, #imgL').on('mouseover', function() {
    this.src = 'someother_image.png';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stop right there**.

You're going about this in a less-than-ideal way.

1. `onmouseover` as an inline attribute is a crappy way of adding event listeners (look at all that duplication)
2. The way you have coded it, it's not really possible to tell (not without adding `this` as each argument)
3. You don't even need JavaScript for this (assuming you want the images to revert when the pointer leaves it)!

Instead, make the `a` elements use an image for their background with CSS (`background-image` property).

Then, on `:hover`, change it, or better still, use a sprite sheet and simply modify the `background-position`.

It will look something like this (move the `id` attributes to the `a` element)...

```
a.lb {
    background-image: url(/images/menu.png);
}

#imgH {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#imgH:hover {
    background-position: 0 -200px;
}
```

Comment: It didn't quite help. By the way, why do we use a.lb when each a has a different background-image?

Comment: @user657592 that relates to the suggestion of using a spritesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you remove the inline script call and use this:

```
$('a.lb img').on('mouseover', function() {
    this.src = new_image_you _want; //this is the var with the image you want
});
```

Code demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9RD5J/)** to get the image you are hovering.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery approach, since you tagged your question such.

Please take a look at the event binder [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), which is a shorthand for chained [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

You can define your image links like such, with `data-alternative-src` as your `mouseover` image path.

```
<a class="lb" href="#">
  <img src="original.png" data-alternative-src="alternative.png" />
</a>
```

We then can cache your original image path to another attribute `data-original-src`, without bloating your HTML code (and web clients that disable Javascript):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.lb img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-original-src', $(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

And on mouse in and mouse out, we switch over to the correct image:

```
$('a.lb').hover(function() {
  var image = $(this).find('img');
  img.attr('src', img.attr('data-alternative-src'));
}, function() {
  var image = $(this).find('img');
  img.attr('src', img.attr('data-original-src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sample Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/FKY74/)

### Working [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/FKY74/2/)  of changing the image on hover

If you are looking for pure javascript the try this

### code

```
function onHover(img)
{
alert(img.id); //image id 

   // do your code
}
```

### html

```
<a class="lb" href="home.php"><img id="imgH" src="Bhome.png" onmouseover="onHover(this);"/></a>
<a class="lb" href="AboutUs.php"><img id ="imgA" src="Babout.png" onmouseover="onHover(this);" /></a>
<a class="lb" href="code.php"><img id ="imgC" src="Bcode.png" onmouseover="onHover(this);" /></a>
<a class="lb" href="login.php"><img id="imgL" src="Blogin.png" onmouseover="onHover(this);" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="lb" href="home.php"><img id="imgH" src="Bhome.png" onmouseover="onHover(this.id);"/></a>

<a class="lb" href="AboutUs.php"><img id ="imgA" src="Babout.png" onmouseover="onHover(this.id);" /></a>

<a class="lb" href="code.php"><img id ="imgC" src="Bcode.png" onmouseover="onHover(this.id);" /></a>

<a class="lb" href="login.php"><img id="imgL" src="Blogin.png" onmouseover="onHover(this.id);" /></a>
```